# Windows Azure Tables, querying using Contains

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to implement a query for one of my Azure Tables, the query should retrieve all files that contain the input string.

I've tried using string.contains() but this isn't supported by Azure, I've also tried string.startswith() this also isn't supported.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to do this in Azure Tables. I'm storing file information in the tables and the partition key is the virtual path of the item stored.

e.g. Images_Jpg_Image1.jpg would be a partition key for one of the files, i've used '_' because Azure won't allow '/' in partition keys.

I'd like to be able to compare the above partition key with

Ideally the following strings would return that partition key

Images_
Images_Jpg
Jpg_
Image1.jpg

I have all the tables set up and all of the other queries, its just this one query that I can't figure out.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table Storage does support the CompareTo method which can be used like a StartsWith. But it still might not work for you based on the types of searching you're trying to do.

```
MyTable.Where(t => t.PartitionKey.CompareTo("image") >= 0).ToList();
```

Comment: This is about the best you could hope for, but it won't find the Jpg_ Image1.jpg case.  It also is case sensitive.  It is also not restricted to items that start with "image".  If you return 1000 results and only the first 300 start with image, you'll get the next 700 items from the table.

Comment: .Where is throwing syntax error for me. I added linq namespace. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I have run into similar issues with searches against Azure tables searching on names and making sure the results were case invariant.

What I ended up doing was actually loading the data I needed from the Azure tables to an in memory collection that gets persisted in a queryable collection. I was then able to use Linq to Objects to query and get the results I wanted.

Not an elegant approach, but if the data collection is not huge and is relativley static, the size of the object in memory will be relatively benign in compassion to how much memory the VM has. Performance was also much faster.

You could also try and just have the Partition/row key and data your are trying to query in memory, run your query, iterate the partiation and row keys and return your results. Not sure if that will help resolve your question, but I throw it out as a possible approach.

Good luck!

John

Comment: Thanks for the response John, I'll have a look into this. I'm tempted to switch to Azure SQL though

Comment: I understand :) For us, it was much cheaper to use the Azure table storage VS SQL. Each case is different, blah, blah, blah :)

Comment: It's worth noting that if the code performing the query is local to the Azure Region (i.e. you've written a service that runs in Azure, "next to" your storage account) then the performance should be ok, and you won't pay for data-transfer ("egress" fees, provided it's in the same Azure -region).  This makes this answer a good one if your application architecture fits into that model.

Answer (score -1):

I found querying Azure Table storage using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) very handy. Check out [Jason Halley's](http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2010/01/28/how-to-query-azure-log-tables-with-linqpad.aspx) blog for more info and samples.